# Continuation when one or more tasks in an array is cancelled or fails?

Tags: c#, task, continuation

If I have an array of tasks, Task[]. How can I write a continuation that only runs when one or more tasks in the array fails(or is cancelled)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the [continuation options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.THREADING.TASKS.TASKCONTINUATIONOPTIONS%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) that you can specify when you [set the continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321576.aspx) for a Task.

```
Task<int> [] tasks = new Task<int>[5];
// Add tasks...

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    task.ContinueWith(a => a.Id, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
}
Task.WaitAny(tasks, new CancellationToken());
```